# Фамилия типа Перец - как склонять?

Tags: склонение-фамилий, фамилии

Известно, что подобные фамилии *славянского* происхождения склоняются с выпадением гласной в суффиксе и переходом ударения на флексию. Тут вопроса нет.

А вот если не славянская? Или заранее неизвестно, славянская ли она, а если и славянская, но носитель о том не подозревает? (не по этой ли причине Шимона Переца переделали в Переса?). Особенно интересует творительный падеж.

Обсуждение на "Грамоте", на мой взгляд, зашло в тупик.

*Предупреждаю во избежание лишних вопросов: иногда перетаскиваю темы с Грамоты, поскольку принять участия там не могу, а уровень тамошнего обсуждения в последнее время "оставляет желать".*

//-----------

Желающих повторить "подвиг" следопыта, убедительно прошу не напрягаться.
Если из текста не будет понятно, как мне написать *"сообщаю, что с [Перец] Ефимом Александровичем я никогда знаком не был"*, то можете не писать ничего. А если понятно, то можете этим и ограничиться.

Comment: Вопрос задан односторонне . Касается только мужской фамилии <<ПЕРЕЦ>> . Дочь еврея с фамилией Перец унаследует от отца ту же фамилию , и в паспорте ей запишут - Перец , а не Перец-а . Следовало бы задать вопрос о склонении этой фамилии в случае с женским носителем . Помимо этого , не показаны другие варианты фамилии <<ПЕРЕЦ>> : Перес , Переш , Перс , вполне возможно , что существовали также и Перш , Перк , Перч . Вопрос заслуживает минуса в силу неполноты постановки .

Comment: *Вопрос задан односторонне* -  Отнюдь.  Все что по делу, все сгодится. Только без притягивания за уши и прочей обычной Вашей каббалистики. Можете взять любую неврейскую или еврейскую ***мужскую*** фамилию на ***-ЕЦ***.  А вот про дочерей сефардов и ашкеназов и прочих любавичских моэлей - в другой раз, пожалуйста. Не интересно.

Comment: Ну , если считать всех "перцев" потомственными русскими , то "каббалистика" , действительно , не требуется . Но это только выше личное мнение . И почему о женской форме нужно "в другой раз" ?! Не логичнее ли обсудить вопрос сразу целиком ?

Comment: А если не считать, то вы и ответить не можете? Мне не интересны Ваши национальные заморочки. В другой раз, кстати, тоже не надо. Флуд потому что.

Answer (score 2):

Перец - Перца - Перцем.

В справочнике по стилистике (Бельчиков Ю.А, 2012) есть раздел "Фамилии (русские и иностранные) на ОК/ЕК/ЕЦ. Фамилии на ЕК/ОК склоняются  с выпадением или сохранением гласного (рассматриваются варианты: Чапек - Чапека, Гавранек - Гавранка), а фамилии на ЕЦ теряют гласный (Грицевец - Грицевца). Для сравнения: фамилии на НЦ сохраняют гласный: Баренц - Баренца, Уманц - Уманца, Уманец - Уманеца.

Кроме того, отдельно рассматриваются фамилии, **совпадающие с нарицательными существительными** (там же названа фамилия Перец). Эти (мужские) фамилии **склоняются с выпадением гласного** (в обычной речи) или **не склоняются вообще** (в официальных случаях).

При этом рекомендуется вместе с фамилией называть имя или должность лица: книга Петра Сокола, защита диссертации Робертом Шериф.

Comment: Спасибо. Бельчиков - это нечто. Всегда обожал его за "вольнодумие". )))  Вот ***Ежи Лец*** бы удивился, почитай он Бельчикова.  Но Вы (или он) забыли одну вещь. Это все справедливо для ***славянских*** фамилий. Я даже постеснялся писать, что уж выпадение-то гласной никак не может быть перенесено на иностранные фамилии.А уж насчет несклонения фамилий в официальной речи - это, простите к доктору.

Comment: *Для сравнения: фамилии на НЦ сохраняют гласный: Баренц - Баренца, Уманц - Уманца, Уманец - Уманеца.* - а вот этого вообще не понял. А чем *Уманец* лучше *Грицевца* - почему о том Бельчиков умалчивает? Вы случайно не "улучшили" ли Юлия Абрамовича? Не надо, он и без Вас всех запутает - не дорого возьмет. )))

Comment: Бельчиков, скорее всего,  считает, что есть две разные фамилии:  Уманц и Уманец.  Кроме того, он, по-видимому,  считает, что любые фамилии (славянские и неславянские) на ЕЦ сохраняют гласный (это не так?). Получается, что Бельчиков  не очень ненадежный  источник по вопросу о фамилиях.  А кого  бы Вы тогда посоветовали в качестве более подходящего  и авторитетного?

Comment: Да я как-то даже немного затрудняюсь... Был бы авторитетный источник - не спрашивал бы. Ну Вот хоть и с Грамоты, но таки грамотный источник.http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/71-rubric-482 Еськова тоже иногда чудит, но не настолько же...

Comment: По поводу же претензий к Бельчикову - да они есть. Рекомендовать несклонение таких фамилий - это нонсенс. Все мужские фамилии на согласный склоняются. Это аксиома. Что касается "Уманец", то её предлагаемое склонение без выпадения гласного противоречит предыдущей рекомендации склонять ч с выпадением всё без разбору. Я и спрашиваю, в чем для "Уманеца" изъятие из общего правила. А не про то, что есть две фамилии Уманец и Уманц (с чем я не сталкивался, но и оспаривать не буду).

Answer (score -1):

На мой взгляд , здесь всё должно определяться тем , какой национальностью позиционирует себя носитель этой фамилии <<ПЕРЕЦ>> . /// Я слышал доподлинную историю о человеке с фамилией <<СОКОЛОВ>> , который свою фамилию неизменно произносил с ударением на перврм слоге С-**о**-колов и всегда поправлял , если кто-то называл его Сокол-**о**-вым . Несомненно , он тем самым отмежёвывался от евреев с фамилией на Сокол- , - среди евреев полно таких фамилий : Сокол , Соколов , Соколецкий , Соколовский и т.п. /// Если носитель считает , что его фамилия от русского названия растения **перец** , то его фамилию следует склонять также , как и это русское слово : Перцу , Перца , Перцем . Аналогично как русские слова с окончанием на **-ец** : молодец , продавец , умелец , тунеядец , будёновец . Если же носитель такой фамилии *не маскируется* , то его фамилию правильно будет склонять , как любую немецкую или немецко-ащкеназскую фамилию на **-ец** / **-иц** . Мы же не говорим : анекдоты про Штирл-**ца** , а говорим : анекдоты про Штирл-**ица** . В случае с еврейским <<ПЕРЕЦ>> , если правильно , то должно склоняться - Пер-**еца** , а не Пер-**ца** . А вот , в случае с женским носителем , фамилия <<ПЕРЕЦ>> склоняться не должна никоим образом . Если бы у Штирлица была жена , то во всех падежах она именовалась бы как *фрау Штирлиц* . Хотя на практике это не соблюдается , - я лично знал медика с фамилией Горовец , который никогда не *маскировался* под русака , и , тем не менее , фамилию его все склоняли , как любое русское слово с окончанием на -**ец** : Горов-**цу** , Горов-**ца** , Горов-**цом** . ///// Дополню примерами фамилий с окончанием на **-ец** : на вскидку , с которыми сам лично сталкивался , - Кривенец , Коломиец , Швец , Горовец , Хейфец , Юхновец . Что касается последней , - Юхновец , то лично знал именно даму с такой фамилией - не склонялась . //// Теперь ещё раз о женской форме . Русских слов женского рода на -**ец** не существует - в женском роде будет не -**ец** , а -**ица** : молод-**ец** - молод-**ица** , жн-**ец** - жн-**ица** , умел-**ец** - умел-**ица** , продав-**ец** - продавщ-**ица** , конькобеж-**ец** - конькобеж-**ица** . Если бы существовал человек с фамилией Продавец , то его фамилию склоняли бы , как и русское слово **продавец** , но , вот , его жена или дочь во всех падежах так бы и оставалась - Продавец . Однако , возьмём случай , когда мужчина носит фамилию с женской формой на -**ица** . Советский художественный фильм "Максим Перепелица" (Ленфильм ,1955 г.) , главный герой по имени Максим с фамилией Перепелица . По ходу , вопрос : *Перепелица* это *перепёлка* , или тут неканоническое имя Перфилий / Перфелий (как фамилия Перфильев) в форме Переф(п)елец (мужск.) / Переф(п)елица (женск.) ? Мне думается , тут *имя* , а не *птица* . В упомянутом советском комедийном фильме женскоподобная фамилия главного героя склоняется точно так же , как и женский род на -**ица** . Само собой , если бы у Максима Перепелицы была , скажем , сестра , то её фамилия склонялась бы , в силу того , что она по форме суть женская . ======================================================================== Для дополнительного чтения . Омоним <<ПЕРЕЦ>> в топонимике : в Одессе - **Переса** , а в Москве - **Пресня** (= П-е-ресня) ; революционная Красная Пресня начиналась с еврейского пролетарского квартала (гипотетически и в Одессе , и в Москве там первоначально поселилось еврейское семейство с фамилией Перец / Перес ) . Омоним <<ПЕРЕЦ>> в русской истории : русский воин **Пересвет** , - это не русское имя , а еврейское ; точно также еврейское имя носит и его *напарник* Осляба ( = еврейское имя Йоселе/-ева /-еба ) .

Comment: Простите, но я просил без кабалистики. Пересы и рабиновичи меня не интересуют. Не хватало еще в правилах склонения оговаривать отдельные случаи для одесских евреев.